# Will Dropmark get rid of my files if I don't upgrade to pro?

Tags: online-storage

I think it's pretty self explanatory. I haven't explicitly read anything of the sort so far, but it'd make sense to delete collection of files that haven't been updated or downloaded for a while. Free cloud services often establish how much time until inactive files are swept away. I mean, it's pretty scary to leave your files without knowing that, right?

So, if anyone knows something, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From their [FAQ](https://www.dropmark.com/support/faq/how-much-storage-space-do-i-have/#stq=&stp=0), free accounts get 500MB storage. I don't see any mention of deleting content after any length of time. Deleting an account seems to require a human to kick off the process.

This seems to be something you should contact them about: support@dropmark.com

---

From the Asker, who *did* contact support:

> Right you are. For future reference, their answer was: "Don't worry, we'll never delete your collections. If your account goes inactive, you may not be able to upload new items, but everything else will still be there until you upgrade again."